# ASP.net - Crystal Reports exporting to PDF adds the letter "i" to certain words randomly

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

We are using Crystal Reports to generate pdf's of customer bills (from a CR template).
It works fine except the engine seems to be adding the letter "i" to random words in the output.  Certain alignment problems are also evident (words overlapping etc).  Standard fonts are being used.

We are using .net 4 and C# linked to the 10.5 CR assemblies.  Latest version of Adobe Acrobat reader is installed on the server.

We have now tried this via 12.2 CR assemblies with the same results. We have also tried multiple .rpt files with the same results.

Comment: The issue still is there. I don't know why they haven't resolved it yet.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, sometimes. I have it on my developer machine and now on Win2k8 x64 but not on my test server Win2k3 x32.

It's a bug somehow in the PDF generation in combination with the Calibri font.
The only solution i have is to use a different font.

Comment: ditto - i have the same problem & the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with Calibri font; I'm using .NET 2.0 and C# with Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2008.

I haven't tested this, but somebody has reported that using a PDF printer instead of exporting to PDF directly from Crystal is a workaround for this problem:
http://community.sagesaleslogix.com/slsl/board/message?message.uid=10777

Comment: Another reference:
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/Reporting_/Crystal_Reports/Q_23013426.html

Answer (score 0):

Printing the document to a printer using PDFCreator instead of directly to a PDF file worked for me.  I have CR 2008 Viewer and Adobe Reader 8.3.

Comment: This doesn't really address the issue of the server generating malformed PDF files. The issue the OP is having occurs during an automated process.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `Calibri` Font. Then I changed the font to a regular font like `Arial, Tahoma, Verdana`. It resolved my issue.

I guess you have used unusual fonts for text fields, formulas, etc objects in `crystal reports`.If you don't want to change your font then try to install required font in production server for `crystal reports`.

Answer (score 0):

That's works for me.

1. Close Crystal Reports designer.
2. Open the Microsoft Registry Editor.
   ( In MS Windows, under the menu Start, select Run, and type: regedit )
3. Navigate to the following path:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\SAP Business Objects\Suite XI 4.0\Crystal Reports\Export\PDF
For CR for VS 32 bit use this key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Crystal Reports\Export\PDF

For CR for VS 64 bit use this key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Crystal Reports\Export\PDF

Note: The last part of the path may not exist. If it is the case, simply add the missing keys. You can add "Export" and "PDF" key with right click and New "Key"

4. Right click on the PDF key, and select: "New - DWORD Value"
5. Set the name to: UseCustomEncoding
6. Set the value to: 0
7. Restart Crystal Reports.

Reference : https://answers.sap.com/questions/306270/extra-characters-when-exporting-crystal-report-to.html